# Pyside QFileDialog.getOpenFileNames how do I get the filename and path as string instead if tuple

Tags: python, pyside

This line of code return the filename and path in unicode, I can't used it. How to get only the filename and string?

**Code:**

```
logfile = QFileDialog.getOpenFileNames(None, caption, directory, filter_mask)[0]

print 'Selected Log file is :', str(logfile)

print logfile
```

**Output:**

```
Selected Log file is : [u'C:\\Temp\\!!!readme.txt']

[u'C:\\Temp\\!!!readme.txt']
```

**Help**
I need logfile to be 'C:\Temp\readme.txt'. How do I do that?

Answer (score 1):

It looks like `QFileDialog.getOpenFileNames` returns a list of strings, so you just have to get the first element:

```
>>> logFile = [u'C:\\Temp\\!!!readme.txt']
>>> f = logFile[0]
>>> f
u'C:\\Temp\\!!!readme.txt'
```

the `u` means that's a unicode string. If you realy don't want unicode just use `str`:

```
>>> str(f)
'C:\\Temp\\!!!readme.txt'
```

Edit: according to [the doc](http://pyqt.sourceforge.net/Docs/PyQt4/qfiledialog.html#getOpenFileNames), it returns a QString list. So you cant use QString methods like `.first()` for instance.

Edit2: wow, I didn't see your `[0]`. It must be too late for me… So, that's weird. Maybe `(QFileDialog.getOpenFileNames(None, caption, directory, filter_mask))[0]`?

Comment: Thanks for you very much for your help. It works using your method. I try using f=str(logfile[0]) does not work. And by the way, it has to be (QFileDialog.getOpenFileNames(None, caption, directory, filter_mask))[0]. (QFileDialog.getOpenFileNames(None, caption, directory, filter_mask)) without [0] does not work.